# updating state in an async function from componentDidMount in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am creating a podcast app using react native. I have stored the information for each of the podcasts in a MySQL database as it is easier to update them. I have used php to filter the information with a query. I then fetch the information and convert it to json format as shown below.

```js
 constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          playState:'paused', //playing, paused
          playSeconds:0,
          duration:0,
          FileUrlHolder: ''
          
      }
      
      this.sliderEditing = false;
  }

  componentDidMount(){
  fetch('http://ee12e879.ngrok.io/Filter.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
       
            // Getting the id.
            id: this.props.navigation.state.params.FlatListClickItemHolder
      })
    }).then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => { 
        this.setState({ 
            FileUrlHolder: responseJson[0].FileUrl 
        }); 
        //console.log(responseJson[0].FileUrl);
        
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    })
```

I use componentDidMount as shown to set the state of the Fileurl from the database/json.

I am using react-native-sound to play each podcast. I then have an play async function where I store the information that allows the function to be played as shown below.

```js
play = async () => {
    console.log(this);
      if(this.sound){
          this.sound.play(this.playComplete);
          this.setState({playState:'playing'});
      }else{
        console.log(this);

        const filepath = this.state.FileUrlHolder;
        console.log('[Play]', filepath);
        
          this.sound = new Sound(filepath, Sound.MAIN_BUNDLE, (error) => {
              if (error) {
                  console.log('failed to load the sound', error);
                  Alert.alert('Notice', 'audio file error. (Error code : 1)');
                  this.setState({playState:'paused'});
              }else{
                  this.setState({playState:'playing', duration:this.sound.getDuration()});
                  this.sound.play(this.playComplete);
              }
          });    
      }
  }
```

In the play function I would like to access the state of the FileUrlHolder so that I can use that information as my file path to be played.

```js
const filepath = this.state.FileUrlHolder;
        console.log('[Play]', filepath);
```

When I do this I don't receive the state of FileUrlHolder and nothing is printed to the console.

Is there any way to use the state of FileUrlHold in the play function. I am new to react native.

Comment: Is the fact that you're defining `play` using an arrow function messing it up? Are you sure `this` is correct inside of the play function?

Comment: when I console.log this in the play function nothing is printed to the console

Comment: Then the way you're defining `play` is probably ruining your `this` context. try defining it instead as `async play(){}`

Comment: it now prints "undefined" to the console

Comment: I don't think I can help you fix this with the information I have now. You're going to have to figure out why `play` doesn't have access to the proper `this` variable. Perhaps you didn't bind it? `this.play = this.play.bind(this);` in the constructor is a common way to do that.

Comment: that sadly didn't fix the problem, no idea what I'm doing or how to fix it

Comment: do you understand at least what the problem is? If you have a react class component, and that class has a method, like `play`, then you can do something like `<button onClick={this.play} />`, right? But if you haven't bound `play` to `this` propertly, then inside the `play` function `this` will be incorrectly defined. One way to do it is bind them in the constructor. Another way is to do something like `<button onClick={this.play.bind(this)} />` or alternatively `<button onClick={() => this.play()} />`

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/this-is-why-we-need-to-bind-event-handlers-in-class-components-in-react-f7ea1a6f93eb/

Comment: yes I understand, thank you

Comment: I worked it out, I needed to wrap everything in my play function with  if(this.state.FileUrlHolder)